# I have three maps in a react component two of which are nested. The inner one is not executing any JSX statements

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I have three maps in a react component two of which are nested. The inner one is not executing any JSX statements. Below as you can see there is a nested map one outer one one inner one in the inner one I also try to console.log but no luck. It is basically a set categories with sub categories. It lists the categories in TABs when I click each tab it should show the subcategories for each category in links.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'
import { Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel } from 'react-tabs';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from '../component/header.jsx'
import CategoryService from '../api/CategoryService.js'
import Array from '../util/Array.js'
import '../css/home.css';
import '../css/react-tabs.css';


class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            categories: [],
            subcategories: [],
            subcategoriesByCategory: [],
            test: [1,2,3]
        }
        this.loadSubCategoriesByCategory = this.loadSubCategoriesByCategory.bind(this)
        this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this)
        this.setSubCatgory = this.setSubCatgory.bind(this)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadData()
    }

    loadData() {
        let  name = ''
        let subcategoriesByCategory = []
        let temp = []
        CategoryService.categories()
            .then( (response) => {
                this.setState({categories: response.data})
          
            this.state.categories.forEach(category => {
                name = category.name
                subcategoriesByCategory =  this.loadSubCategoriesByCategory(category.name)
                temp.push({subcategories: subcategoriesByCategory})
            })
            this.setState({subcategories: temp})  
        })
    }

    loadSubCategoriesByCategory(category){
        let result = []
        CategoryService.subcategoriesOfCategory(category)
         .then((res) => {
           Array.copy(res.data,result)
        })
        return result
    }

    setSubCatgory(category){
        this.setState({subcategoriesByCategory: this.loadSubCategoriesByCategory(category)})
    }

  
    render() {
        return (   
            <div>
            <Header/>
            <Tabs className="center-tabs">
            <TabList>   
                    {
                        this.state.categories.map (
                            category =>
                            <>
                                <Tab>{category.name}</Tab> 
                            </>
                        )
                    }    
            </TabList>
            <TabPanel>
                    {
                            this.state.subcategories.map(
                                subcategory => {                            
                                    subcategory.subcategories.map(
                                         subcategoryByCategory => {
                                        return (
                                            <div>
                                                <Link key={subcategoryByCategory.name}>{subcategoryByCategory.name}</Link>
                                                {console.log(subcategoryByCategory)}                                        
                                            </div>)
                                         })
                                    })
                    }
            </TabPanel>
              </Tabs>   
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Home)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `return` before you call `subcategory.subcategories.map`... this is needed because the block is inside curly braces.

Alternatively, you could just remove the curly braces that follow `subcategoryByCategory =>` and the statement will be returned implicity.